# What's the difference between these two methods to drop a database?

Tags: sql-server, database

I always use the following code to drop a database in SQL Server.

```
IF DB_ID('mydatabase') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE mydatabase;
```

But in `Paul S Randal`'s MCM video, I saw code like this:

```
IF DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('mydatabase', 'Version') > 0
    DROP DATABASE mydatabase;
```

What's the diffference? Is the second way faster than the first one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no significant difference.  I'll even give you another option:

```
IF EXISTS(
    select *
    from master.sys.databases
    where name = 'mydatabase')
DROP DATABASE mydatabase;
```

There are always many ways to do the same thing.  But from personal experience, DB_ID is both the shortest to write out and probably fastest too.

Various ways to access information about databases

- sys.databases http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx (2005 onwards)
- sysdatabases (don't use for future work)
- DB_ID http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx (7.0+)
- databasepropertyex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx (2000+)
- databaseproperty http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176049.aspx (7.0 to 2008 R2, don't use for future work)

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, there's not any difference.  The IF statement is merely there to keep you from receiving an error when you call the DROP DATABASE command (i.e. it's a check for existence).

And with a high cost action such as a DROP DATABASE, the millisecond differences inherit in their respective existence checks is somewhat...irrelevant..

Now if you were looking for information about a database, then DATABASEPROPERTYEX  is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if a database exists so you can drop it, use DB_ID.

If you only want to drop an open database then use DATABASEPROPERTYEX. The version number of a closed database is null. Dropping a closed database or one with offline files will not remove the files from disk.

Other than that, performance is not an issue.